# Is the Park Service continuing its case to re-rename Yosemite Park's historic landmarks?

Tags: united-states, national-parks, yosemite

I have often checked into the Ahwahnee in Yosemite Valley after emerging, filthy and undernourished, from the backcounty.  A hot shower in one of the cottages, an Ahwahnee Burger, a glass (or three) of wine and boysenberry pie a la mode delivered to the cottage patio -- bliss!

Imagine my shock when I heard that the Ahwahnee had been renamed The Majestic because the former concessionaire had trademarked its name, and that of Curry Village and several other historic places.  The [San Francisco Chronicle](http://www.sfchronicle.com/bayarea/article/How-Yosemite-lost-its-historic-names-and-may-6883006.php) said on March 11, 2016:

> The park’s new concessionaire has gone as far as halting sales of
>   “Yosemite National Park” T-shirts because of its predecessor’s claim
>   to the park title. The name “Yosemite” is being used instead.

The article said that the Park Service had not given up and was fighting the case, but I have not found anything more recent on the subject.

What is happening?  What is an informed prognosis on the outcome of the legal battle?  The Majestic sounds like a Las Vegas hotel, but I better stop before I rant.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The name change is going ahead, at least for now

> The Ahwahnee Hotel and other Yosemite National Park landmarks soon will be renamed amid a legal dispute between the government and the facilities' outgoing operator.
>
> On March 1, the famed Ahwahnee — a name affixed to countless trail guides and family memories — will become the Majestic Yosemite Hotel. And Curry Village, a collection of cabins near the center of the park that has carried the same name since the 1800s, will become Half Dome Village, park spokesman Scott Gediman said Thursday.
>
> “This is not something we did willingly,” said Gediman, noting that the government was fighting to reclaim the old names in hopes that they someday will be restored.

A few other things are going to be changed

> Also affected will be:
>
> Yosemite Lodge at the Falls, becoming Yosemite Valley Lodge.
>
> Wawona Hotel, becoming Big Trees Lodge.
>
> Badger Pass Ski Area, becoming Yosemite Ski & Snowboard Area.

[Source](http://www.latimes.com/local/lanow/la-me-ln-yosemite-ahwahnee-hotel-20160114-story.html) (Jan 14,2017)

With that said, I have seen the government change the names of a few landmarks, and usually the locals continue refer to them by their old names.

Comment: Bah! If they really wanted to fix it they could deliberately punch a hole in trademark law.